# How to create an attribute?

Tags: xml, xslt

my xml

```
<article>
 <section>
  <title id="chapter-introduction">Introduction</title>

  <para>Some text</para>
 </section>

 <section>
  <title>Problem description</title>

  <para>Some text</para>
  <para>Please click <link linkend="chapter-introduction">here</link> to
    go to the Introduction chapter.</para>
 </section>
</article>
```

my xsl

```
<xsl:template match="section/title">
 <H2>
  <xsl:attribute name="id">
   <xsl:value-of select="@id" />
  </xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
 </H2>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="link">
 <u>    
  <a style="color:green" href="#{@linkend}"> 
   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </a>
 </u>
</xsl:template>
```

I want to create internal links in the output html document. My templates are created in every "section/title" attribute id, but I do not want to get the id attribute with the value "null".
In output I want get `<H2 id="chapter-introduction">Introduction</H2>` ... `<H2>Problem description</H2>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can surround the `<xsl:attribute>` with a test checking for the presence of the `id` attribute, so it will only be processed if the `<title>` actually contains it:

```
<xsl:if test="@id">
    <xsl:attribute name="id">
        <xsl:value-of select="@id" />
     </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:if>
```

Answer (score 3):

How about something simple:

```
<xsl:template match="section/title">
    <H2>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@id" />
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </H2>
</xsl:template>
```